# Deploying to ETH mainnet with Remix Gas Fees

Tags: remix, mainnet

When deploying with Remix to ETH mainnet, is it fine to leave the max gas fee as Remix suggests? It seems to be low and I don't want the deployment to fail. Metamask suggests a much higher gas fee. It seems Remix sets the gas fee below the "low" gas fee at the time.

The gas amount is 6707048.

Please can someone who has deployed a contract on mainnet with Remix advise.

Comment: trust metamask and check this https://ethgasstation.info/ for actual prices

Comment: @MajdTL Thank you! So if Metamask is much higher than ethgasstation, do I just go with Metamask?

Comment: I shouldn't be much higher. here is another alternative to gas station https://etherscan.io/gastracker if you can add some pictures or more information it would be great

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Hu9ypY2
So the remix image shows remix suggestion
Then the other two are metamask, one is straight after confirming and one is editing the gas fee and selecting medium transaction time.

Comment: I would trust metamask more but it is up to you  :). maybe try first try to deploy on rinkeby just to be sure that your contract and metamask is okay

Comment: Cool yeah I have deployed it a lot to Rinkeby with no issues. I am going go with metamasks suggestion, it seems to be more accurate. Thanks @MajdTL!